# Using PGFPlots to draw lines with semilogyaxis with negative y values

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw lines with log y mode using PGFPlots.

I have a table looking like the following:

```
0.00097656 -56126
0.0019531 -53585
0.0039062 -33705
0.0078125 -25956
0.015625 -18886
0.03125 -10538
0.0625 -12273
0.125 -8532.3
0.25 -7443.9
0.5 -7443.9
1 -7407.8
2 -5200.3
4 -21963
8 -21963
16 -21963
32 -21963
64 -21963
```

which has negative y values.
When I try to use log y axis, it gives me nothing as the range of y axis is from 10^0 to 10^1. How can I scale the y axis and get the image?

I can use matlab to get the wanted image like the following:

[image]

Comment: log function is not defined for negative numbers

Comment: yeah, for a number like -56126, we can process it as -5.6126*10^4, which did the trick. Matlab actually handles it this way, but I don't know if pgfplot supports such feature.

Comment: how does it handle? 5.6e-4 is a different thing that log axis. I don't think matlab does anything like that. You can cook up something like that but it is not clear which one you want.

Comment: Thanks for your editing. :) I attached the matlab plot here. It puts negative before the power.

Comment: Or you can use `log(|y|)` with no hack on the log function

Comment: I can do that. But it brings some trouble to explain.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by first negating the y values to get positive numbers, and then again negate the labels of the y values.

Please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{loglogaxis}[
            log basis x=2,
            ymin=1e3,
            ymax=1e5,
            % show the `yticklabels' as negative values
            log base 10 number format code/.code={
                $-10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{#1}}$
            },
        ]
            \addplot table [
                x index=0,
                % because negative log values are not defined,
                % make them positive
                y expr=-\thisrowno{1},
            ] {
                0.00097656 -56126
                0.0019531 -53585
                0.0039062 -33705
                0.0078125 -25956
                0.015625 -18886
                0.03125 -10538
                0.0625 -12273
                0.125 -8532.3
                0.25 -7443.9
                0.5 -7443.9
                1 -7407.8
                2 -5200.3
                4 -21963
                8 -21963
                16 -21963
                32 -21963
                64 -21963
            };
        \end{loglogaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Would it be possible to apply this trick if both axes have the same logarithmic base?

Comment: @aaragon, without testing it I cannot image why this shouldn't work for `loglogaxis` as well. Just give it a try. If you cannot make it work, don't hesitate to ask a new question ... Good luck!